# is there a way to revert an image back to it's orignal size, once it has been set to a percentage size?

Tags: css

When creating a responsive design layout with a grid, often the image size is set to 100% after a breakpoint...that way the image won't grow bigger than the grid col, but it will get smaller on windows resize.However sometimes at another breakpoint I need the image to revert back to the original size, because the grid column could go from 50% to 100% on a small device.
Is there a way revert the image back to it's original size using css?

Comment: Doing and undoing styles is rather inefficient.  It would be better to specify that an image is 100% wide between specific viewport widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course :)

```
 width: auto;
```

And with CSS you'll need to put this under the original rule, unless the ones above are more sepsific. So if thats the case, make it more targeted, again if thats not an option use the dreaded `!important` rule.

Comment: Wasn't aware that auto reset it back. Thanks.